# GraphViz Dot layout of nodes without an edge

Tags: layout, graphviz, dot

I'm calculating quite big layouts with the GraphViz dot layout. My source structure is a graph where some nodes are connected and others not. The layout for the connected nodes is perfect, but dot alignes all other nodes in a straight row, which leads to a quite huge length of the output. Is there any change to get rid of this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a program called [`unflatten`](http://www.graphviz.org/pdf/unflatten.1.pdf) in the Graphviz suite that can be used for this. An example of usage:

```
unflatten -c 2 graph.dot | dot -Tpng -o graph.png
```

where you tell unflatten to chain disconnected nodes up to a length of 2. This will create invisible edges that prevent the nodes from being lined up as you describe. For more details, see [the documentation](http://www.graphviz.org/pdf/unflatten.1.pdf).